# How to efficiently get multiple outputs for a given set of inputs?

Tags: publications, productivity

**Background:** I was reading about [Google's Hybrid approach to research](http://cacm.acm.org/magazines/2012/7/151226-googles-hybrid-approach-to-research/fulltext). This prompted me to think about how in academia I try to get multiple output from the one set of inputs. For example, I might try to

- Present a talk and and then write up a journal article
- Write blog posts and question-and-answer combos on StackExchange to force me to learn something that I need to know in order to write a journal article.
- If I learn a new technique in the process of writing a journal article, then present a tutorial on how to apply the technique.

I've also heard senior academics talk about employing this approach. E.g.,

- publishing an article in a journal as well as reframing the content for a magazine or newspaper

#### Question

- What are the most important examples of getting multiple outputs for a given input?
- What is a systematic way of incorporating this into your project planning?

Answer (score 6):

Your answer to this question will depend somewhat on your long term goals.  Everything you mention: talks, journal articles, blog posts, tutorials, magazine articles, etc. can be worthwhile in the right circumstances.  Most of what you describe consists of taking variations on the **same theme** to **different audiences**.

In what circles do you most want to be known?  More generally, **how will you measure success?**  Say for example that your primary goal is to get tenure.  If you're at a high research school, then publishing an expository article for undergraduates may well be viewed (by your tenure committee) as a waste of your time.  In contrast, if you're at a liberal arts school, this may be considered just as valuable as getting a research article in a top journal.

You asked about incorporating this into project planning.  I suggest that you **decide which audiences you are most excited to reach**.  This will likely be largely *independent* of the particular project.  Then as you start on each project, think about how you can **tailor your message to suit each of these audiences**.  You may be surprised by how often you find you have something valuable to say to each of your target groups.

Answer (score 5):

I've heard of more than one team who produce for each chunk of research

1. a workshop paper describing what is planned, the challenges, requirements, etc.
2. a conference paper describing the results.
3. a journal version of the conference paper, expanding on the results, providing more detail, etc.

I think this is not a bad approach, as it certainly helps to give better shape to the ideas by the time they reach the journal version. (I don't use this approach, though.)